# How to remove duplicate values from hash of arrays with 2 references

Tags: perl

I have a hash of hash of arrays. The keys to the hashes are `$duration` and `$attr`. I want to sort descending `$b <=> $a` and remove only those duplicate values, which have equal duration. In the snippet these should be streams:

`'h264/AVC, 1080p24 /1.001 (16:9)' & 'AC3, English, multi-channel, 48kHz'` 
with duration `'26'` but not the duplicate values with $duration `'2124'` & `'115'`.

There are countless examples for removing duplicates and I've tried everything I could find to implement for my needs but with no success. What should be my approach for the solution. Thanks.

```
my ( %recordings_by_dur_attr ) = ();

push( @{ $recordings_by_dur_attr{ $duration }{ $attr } }, @stream );

print Data::Dumper->Dump( [\%recordings_by_dur_attr] );
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '2124' => {
                  '00300.mpls, 00-35-24' => [
                                              '',
                                              'h264/AVC, 480i60 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                              'AC3, English, stereo, 48kHz'
                                            ]
                },
      '50' => {
                00021.mpls, 00-00-50' => [
                                            '',
                                            'h264/AVC, 1080p24 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                            'AC3, English, multi-channel, 48kHz'
                                          ]
              },
      '6528' => {
                  '00800.mpls, 01-48-48' => [
                                              '',
                                              'Chapters, 18 chapters',
                                              'h264/AVC, 1080p24 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                              'DTS, Japanese, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS Master Audio, English, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, French, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, Italian, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, German, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, Spanish, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, Portuguese, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, Spanish, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, Russian, stereo, 48kHz'
                                            ]
                },
      '26' => {
                '01103.mpls, 00-00-26' => [
                                            '',
                                            'h264/AVC, 1080p24 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                            'AC3, English, multi-channel, 48kHz'
                                          ],
                '01102.mpls, 00-00-26' => [
                                            '',
                                            'h264/AVC, 1080p24 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                            'AC3, English, multi-channel, 48kHz'
                                          ],
                '00011.mpls, 00-00-26' => [
                                            '',
                                            'h264/AVC, 1080p24 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                            'AC3, English, multi-channel, 48kHz'
                                          ]
              },
      '115' => {
                 '00304.mpls, 00-01-55' => [
                                             '',
                                             'h264/AVC, 480i60 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                             'AC3, English, stereo, 48kHz'
                                           ]
               }
    };
```

Duplicate structure

```
 '',
'h264/AVC, 1080p24 /1.001 (16:9)',
'AC3, English, multi-channel, 48kHz'
```

Wanted result with removed duplicate structure:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '2124' => {
                  '00300.mpls, 00-35-24' => [
                                              '',
                                              'h264/AVC, 480i60 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                              'AC3, English, stereo, 48kHz'
                                            ]
                },
      '50' => {
                00021.mpls, 00-00-50' => [
                                            '',
                                            'h264/AVC, 1080p24 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                            'AC3, English, multi-channel, 48kHz'
                                          ]
              },
      '6528' => {
                  '00800.mpls, 01-48-48' => [
                                              '',
                                              'Chapters, 18 chapters',
                                              'h264/AVC, 1080p24 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                              'DTS, Japanese, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS Master Audio, English, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, French, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, Italian, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, German, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, Spanish, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, Portuguese, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, Spanish, stereo, 48kHz',
                                              'DTS, Russian, stereo, 48kHz'
                                            ]
                },
      '26' => {
                '00011.mpls, 00-00-26' => [
                                            '',
                                            'h264/AVC, 1080p24 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                            'AC3, English, multi-channel, 48kHz'
                                          ]
              },
      '115' => {
                 '00304.mpls, 00-01-55' => [
                                             '',
                                             'h264/AVC, 480i60 /1.001 (16:9)',
                                             'AC3, English, stereo, 48kHz'
                                           ]
               }
    };
```

Post processing

```
for my $duration ( sort { $b <=> $a } keys %recordings_by_dur_attr ) {
   for my $attr ( keys $recordings_by_dur_attr{ $duration }  ) {

       #Remove duplicate structures

        my @stream = @{ $recordings_by_dur_attr{ $duration }{ $attr } };
        my ( $mpls, $hms ) = ( $attr =~ /(\d+\.mpls), (\d+-\d+-\d+)$/ );
        for ( my $i = 1;  $i < @stream; $i++ ) {

        #extract info from each stream

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After I sort and remove the duplicates I want to count and additionally process each stream (e.g. get the language) from each playlist and extract mpls number and timestamp from the $attr.

Comment: I apologize. Obviously I misunderstood your request. I posted what should be considered a duplicate structure - multiple streams. I'd like to compare those multiples streams with each playlist and remove the duplicate ones, which have equal $duration.

Comment: I want to remove those duplicate structures because they are identical playlists and in that sense they are redundant. My final goal is to automate a process for extracting the codec streams, which would be time consuming if many such streams are present. In some scenarios I'm talking about 20-30 playlists.

Comment: btw, `$hashref` would be a very poor name for a variable that actually contains a hash reference, but to name a hash `%hashref` is just plain bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `$seen{$candidate}++` is useful for finding duplicates. When it returns true, `$candidate` has previously been seen. It is most often used as follows:

```
my @uniq = grep !$seen{$_}++, @list;
```

Instead of building a list of keys of elements to keep, I inverted the condition to build a list of keys of elements to delete.

```
sub id { pack 'N/(N/a*)', @{ $_[0] } }

for my $recordings_by_attr (values(%recordings_by_dur_attr)) {
   my %seen;
   delete @{$recordings_by_attr}{
       grep $seen{id($recordings_by_attr->{$_})}++,
        sort
         keys %$recordings_by_attr
   };
}
```

The `sort` decides which of the duplicates to remove. If you don't care which, you can remove the `sort`.

Comment: Many, many thanks ikegami. I changed the bad naming to match your suggestion and obviously this is the solution but I keep getting an error: `Can't use string $attr as an ARRAY ref while "strict ref" in use at sub id { pack 'N/(N/a*)', @$_ }`. Am I missing something

Comment: Yessss!!! You made my day. Unlimited thanks. The missing piece in my puzzle was `sub id { pack 'N/(N/a*)', @{ $_[0] } }`, which is the key for the solution in my case, because I've already tried the `grep !$seen{$_}++` many times. Thanks again.

Comment: You need a function (in the mathmatical sense) F where F(A) eq F(B) for all duplicates A,B; and where F(A) ne F(B) for all differing A,B. It doesn't matter what the value is, as long as it meets the above definition. `grep $seen{ join "\n", @$_ },` would do if the values in the arrays can't contain newlines, but went with a solution that handles every string.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

```
    1. Traverse the hash.
    2. if ref $key eq "ARRAY"
       then 
       1. my `@temp = uniq(@{$hash->{$key}})`;
       2. $var = undef;
       3. $var = \@temp;
       Else
       1. Traverse the hash.
    3. Else
       1. next;
```